# Laravel fallback view

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I need to return a default view if a particular view is not available. I expect something like `return view(['order.create', 'base.create'], ['params' => $params]);` Can I achieve this without having set of if statements in Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
return view()->first(['order.create', 'base.create'], ['params' => $params]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simpler Method**

1. Go to `app/config/view.php`
2. Under `paths`, add new view path, for example:

```php
    'paths' => [
        resource_path('base/views'),
        resource_path('views'),
    ],
```

3. Use `view()` function without `first()` and array.

```
return view('order.create', compact('params'))
```

This will load views for `base/views` directory first, if not found, then find in the `views` directory. Then you can put blade files and directory with same structure.